# Identityserver external login to local

Tags: vue.js, identityserver4

I'm trying to implement Identityserver4 as an IDP to a Vue.JS SPA app. I have everything setup and configured correctly out of the box. I can login using local accounts, Google or Microsoft and the tokens and profiles are returned correctly to the app. However, I don't want just anyone who's authenticated with an external provider to be able to use this app, they still need to be validated against a local repository of users. I've been searching the net for quite some time on how to intercept a successful external login in IdentityServer and validate their email exists in my repository. Then, if found, add custom claims to the token.  Anyone have any samples on this process?